# Vue Chart JS options aren't used

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js

I'm using Vue Chart JS v3.5.1 in my Nuxt JS/Vue project, and I've noticed that when trying to use options and pass them as a prop, nothing happens, the chart defaults back to the chart's default settings despite me overwriting settings.

I've got several files:

- plugins/LineChart.js
- components/LineChart.vue

**plugins/LineChart.js**

```js
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  computed: {
    localOptions: function() {
      return this.chartOptions
    },
    localData: function() {
      console.log(`data: ${this.chartData}`)
      return this.chartData
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.renderLineChart()
  },
  methods: {

    /*
    ** Render a line chart
    */
    renderLineChart () {

      // this.chartdata is created in the mixin.
      // If you want to pass options please create a local options object
      this.renderChart(this.localData, this.localOptions)
    }

  },
  watch: {
    chartData: {
      handler: function (val, oldVal) {
        this._data._chart.destroy()
        this.renderLineChart()
      },
      deep: true
    },
    chartOptions: {
      handler: function (val, oldVal) {
        this.localOptions = val
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
}
```

**components/LineChart.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <line-chart :chart-data="customChartData" :chart-options="customChartOptions" class="data-chart"></line-chart>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.data-chart canvas {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
</style>

<script>
import LineChart from '~/plugins/LineChart.js'
export default {
  components: {
    LineChart
  },
  props: {
    labels: {
      type: Array,
      default: null
    },
    datasets: {
      type: Array,
      default: null
    },
    options: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({})
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      customChartData: {},
      customChartOptions: {}
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.fillData()
  },
  methods: {
    fillData () {
      this.customChartData = {
        labels: this.labels,
        datasets: this.datasets
      }
      this.customChartOptions = {
        options: this.options
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My usage, is then reasonably simple, yet I'm not getting my options to show?

```html
<LineChart
  :options="{
    responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              display: false
            },
            ticks: {
              autoSkip: true,
              maxTicksLimit: 3,
              maxRotation: 0,
              minRotation: 0
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            gridLines: {
              display: true,
              color: '#f3f5f6'
            }
          }]
        },
        elements: {
          point: {
            radius: 0,
            hitRadius: 35
          }
        }
  }"
  :labels="['test']"
  :datasets="[{
    fill: false,
    borderWidth: 2.5,
    pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderColor: '#5046e5',
    data: [500,
  }]"
/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE

In addition, I seem to only have the first chart out of many charts on the page show data, why would only one chart in a series of charts show data, I've got a key on each one.

Answer (score 0):

in your fillData it looks like you assign the options wrong. Vue Chartjs expects an object with the options in it and not an object with an field options with the options.

If you change: `this.customChartOptions = {options: this.options}` to: `this.customChartOptions = this.options` it should work

Comment: i've got options working now, but bizarely, I'm only getting the first chart of many charts on my page to show data. For example, I have 3 completely different charts, and only the first is showing data, if I "comment out" the first chart, then the second chart shows data. I've got a `key` on my `<line-chart>` component...